# How to register an app in adobe app measurement or adobe omniture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, adobe-analytics

I have following question on adobe omniture

1. How we can register an iPhone app
2. How we can view all tracks or report of our iPhone app
3. What is s.account and how we can get it from omiture

   omniture = [[AppMeasurement alloc] init];

   ```
   omniture.account = @"mykey";
   omniture.ssl = YES;
   omniture.trackingServerSecure = @"myserver";
   omniture.trackingServer = @"myserver";
   omniture.currencyCode = @"USD";
   omniture.debugTracking = YES;
   omniture.OfflineThrottleDelay = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
   omniture.offlineLimit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:300];
   omniture.trackOffline = true;
       NSDictionary *chrumMeasureDict = [configData objectForKey:@"churnMeasure"];
       ChurnMeasurement *c = [omniture getChurnInstancePopulateDefaults:NO];
       [c setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:chrumMeasureDict];
       omniture.useBestPractices = YES;
   ```

   and then of course on the events I have

   NSMutableDictionary *trackData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
       for (NSDictionary *datadict in eventData) {

   ```
       [trackData setValue:[datadict objectForKey:@"value"] forKey:[datadict objectForKey:@"event"]];

   }
   [omniture track:trackData];
   ```

Any small help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You do not need to register an iPhone app with Omniture. Implementing code to send data to SiteCatalyst is enough to populate their reports.
2. In order to view reports that your app is sending to Adobe's data collection servers, you must login to the Digital Marketing Suite interface at http://my.omniture.com.
3. The s.account variable determines the report suite ID you send data to. A report suite ID tells Adobe's servers which reports to populate. To locate the report suite ID, login to SiteCatalyst and go to Admin | Admin Console | Report Suites. From there you will see the full list of report suites with their associated IDs.